# iOS 15 SDK - `memcpy()` not exported

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios15

I've been using `memcpy` in some Dart/Flutter code (through FFI), but with the latest Xcode + iOS 15 simulator, it's not available anymore (`Failed to lookup symbol (dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, memcpy): symbol not found`). Anyone an idea why they've hidden the symbol in the runtime? And more importantly, if there's a way to get it back? Maybe some library to link in the podspec or something?

The code in question is

```dart
typedef _dart_memcpy = void Function(Pointer<Uint8>, Pointer<Uint8>, int);
typedef _c_memcpy = Void Function(Pointer<Uint8>, Pointer<Uint8>, IntPtr);

late final memcpy = DynamicLibrary.process().lookupFunction<_c_memcpy, _dart_memcpy>('memcpy');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue in Flutter v2.5.1 (currrent stable), not present in current beta channel.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/90896#issuecomment-930052186

Comment: I have it also in v2.5.2